# Sphinx not showing as installed

Tags: ubuntu, sphinx

I've been following multiple tutorials:
http://zrashwani.com/introduction-to-sphinx/#.VsCSf5MrKb8
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-sphinx-on-ubuntu-14-04

And I keep hitting a wall. I've followed every step to the dot yet anytime I use the command "search" through SSH I get the following message:

The program 'search' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install sphinxsearch

Now, I definitely have sphinxsearch installed. Infact I can do everything from running indexer:

```
root@panel:/usr/bin# indexer --all
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'videos_index'...
collected 1 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 1 docs, 148 bytes
total 0.005 sec, 25539 bytes/sec, 172.56 docs/sec
indexing index 'delta'...
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.001 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
total 8 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 19 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

and I can even turn on searchd:

```
root@panel:/usr/bin# searchd
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
precaching index 'videos_index'
precaching index 'delta'                                    
precached 2 indexes in 0.002 sec
```

But as soon as I try to run a test search, I get the message:

```
root@panel:/usr/bin# search test
The program 'search' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

What am I doing wrong? 
This is on digitalocean droplet running Ubuntu 14.04 and VestaCP

Answer (score 0):

If you have it installed properly, it's not `search`, it's `searchd`. Assuming you installed according the default instructions, you should find the daemon in `/usr/local/sphinx/bin/`.

Before running it, you need to run the `indexer` which is also in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The **search** program has been removed in the new spninx releases. use **SphinxQL** to test sphinx.

See the new tutorial for Sphinx at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-sphinx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Disclaimer: I am the author of the article.